# How is this private data member of a base class being accessed by a derived class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a private data member called balance in a base class called bankAccount. I wanted my derived class checkingAccount to be able to use balance so I made it protected but i've noticed that my derived class seems to be able to still access balance even when it is put in the private section of my base class. I thought this was impossible? Does anyone know what muight be going on?

**Base Class:**

```
class bankAccount
    {
        public:
        bankAccount();
        void setAccountInfo(int accountNumTemp, double balanceTemp);
        void applyTransaction(char accountType, char transactionTypeTemp, int amountTemp, int j);

        private:
        int accountNumber;
        double balance;
    };
```

**Derived Class:**

```
class checkingAccount: public bankAccount
{
    public:
    checkingAccount();
    double applyTransaction(char transactionTypeTemp, int amountTemp, int c, double balance);

    private:
    float interestRate;
    int minimumBalance;
    float serviceCharge;

};
```

**base class function member where the derived class function member receives the datamember in question:**

```
void bankAccount:: applyTransaction(char accountType, char transactionTypeTemp, int amountTemp, int j)
{
    int c;
    c = j;

    checkingAccount ca;

            balance = ca.applyTransaction(transactionTypeTemp, amountTemp, c, balance);
}
```

**Derived Class function member where the private data member of Base Class is used:**

```
double checkingAccount:: applyTransaction(char transactionTypeTemp, int amountTemp, int c, double balance)
{
  if (transactionTypeTemp == 'D')
        {
            balance = balance + amountTemp;
        }
  else if (transactionTypeTemp == 'W')
        {
            if (balance < amountTemp)
            {
            cout << "error: transaction number " << c + 1 << " never occured due to insufficent funds." << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                balance = balance - amountTemp;
                if(balance < minimumBalance) //if last transaction brought the balance below minimum balance
                {
                   balance = (balance - serviceCharge); //apply service charge
                }
            }
        }

        return balance;
}
```

Comment: **Don't derive from a base class that has no virtual destructor.** Please.

Comment: Oh, and please never store financial data as floating point values in a real-life application. The rounding errors are sure to evaporate or create money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checkingAccount::applyTransaction` doesn't see or touch the base class's `balance` member. It's using, resetting and returning its own `balance` argument.

Comment: This is what I figured at first also, however, my output indicates that the value of balance in the derived function that has some operations performed on it is the same value of the base class balance

Comment: @Matt: where you calling `applyTransaction` on a `checkingAccount` through a pointer/reference to `bankAccount`?

Comment: So I guess the question then is, how is the new balance getting the value as the old balance?

Comment: @Matt: please answer my question, because if you did what I described, the solution is simple.

Comment: hmm, not sure. I am calling bankAccounts applytransaction in main then inside of bankAccounts apply transaction, checkingAccounts applyTransaction is called.

Comment: Does the latter call look like `backAccount *a = new checkingAccount; a.applyTransaction(...)`?

Comment: nope: ca.applyTransaction(transactionTypeTemp, amountTemp, c, balance); [ca is the checkingAccount object instance i believe]

Comment: @Matt: I believe I misunderstood your problem. What were you expecting to see?

Comment: If the new balance in checkingAccounts applyTransactions is not the same balance that is in bankAccount, why do the two seem to have the same value? I am expecting the new uninitialized balance to just be whatever random number is in memory and my output to be all wrong, but my output indicates that balance is what I want it to be, balance from bankAccount.

Comment: @Matt: please edit the question and paste some code that shows the unexpected behavior. This isn't getting much clearer, given that you commented to the other answer that "the value of the new balance is the same as the value of the old balance".

Comment: Since this is sort of a different question, I'll accept your answer and post a new one that hopefully better explains the situation better when I am able. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

`balance` in that context is the 4th argument to the function (`checkingAccount:: applyTransaction`); it is not the data member of `bankAccount`.

Comment: This is what I figured at first also, however, my output indicates that the value of balance in the derived function that has some operations performed on it is the same value of the base class balance

Comment: @Matt You're updating private member variable balance after you finish applyTransaction, so of course it'll be the same once that's over.  Are you saying it changes during applyTransaction?

Comment: im saying the value of the new balance is the same as the value of the old balance. shouldn't the value of the new balance be whatever is in memory if it is not initialized?